# How to use tabs with vim in the Linux "screen" program?

Tags: linux, vim, tmux, gnu-screen, screenrc

When I use the Linux `screen` program, pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key will move between multiple screen windows. But when I want to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to add blank space in a file using vim, it is useless, and will move to another screen. How can I use <kbd>Tab</kbd> with vim in `screen`?

**EDIT**: (taken from comments)

I have this keybinding in my `.screenrc` file:

```
escape ^Ii
```

And if I remove that, the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key works again.

Comment: That is not a default screen keybinding. Normally the tab key is just the tab key. Your `.screenrc` file likely has a key binding for tab, which you would need to disable in order to use it normally again.

Comment: @DanLowe tanks for your answer. I checked the `.screenrc` file, when I delete the `escape ^Ii`, the `tab` keyboard is normal with vim, and the the tab completion is also normal use at the shell. so, I think the `escape ^Ii` effect the `tab`.but I can't understand why the `escape ^Ii` will effect the `tab` keyboard, and can't find a good way to solute this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `escape ^Ii` entry in the `.screenrc` file.

In many/most terminal emulators, `^I` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>) is the same key code as the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key (ASCII 0x11, aka "TAB" or "Horizontal Tab").

So the only solution is to choose a different escape key for use in screen.